# How to plot time series in a colored grid fashion based on cell string in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to generate a plot like this
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P3id.png) in matplotlib

Based on a pandas dataframe constructed like this:

```
   2020-01-01  2020-01-02  2020-01-03  ...
X    yellow        red         red     ...
Y    orange       orange       red     ...
Z     red         yellow     yellow    ...
...   ...          ...         ...     ...
```

I thought it might be done with 2D histograms but had no luck. i've seen that `pcolor` might be the func i'm looking for but i can't manage it to work with my time serie dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot with `seaborn`. You need to replace the colors with numbers, so you'll have a dataframe like this:

[image: dataframe]

And you can use `sns.heatmap` to plot:

[image: heatmap]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

data = {'date': pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-01-31", freq="1D").strftime('%d %b'),
        'a': np.random.randint(3, size=31), 'b': np.random.randint(3, size=31),
        'c': np.random.randint(3, size=31), 'd': np.random.randint(3, size=31),
        'e': np.random.randint(3, size=31), 'f': np.random.randint(3, size=31)}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df = df.set_index('date')
df = df.transpose()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,2])
ax = sns.heatmap(df, cmap=['yellow', 'orange', 'red'], cbar=False)
```

If you prefer `matplotlib` you can use `imshow`:

[image: imshow]

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,2])
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(df.columns)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(df.index)))
ax.set_xticklabels(df.columns)
ax.set_yticklabels(df.index)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
ax.imshow(df, ListedColormap(['yellow', 'orange', 'red']))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much!